# How to check filename before its upload in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

What I intended to do is when I click to upload button, the system will check whether the selected file name is same with the file name that I want or not (before the file is upload).

```
string selectedValue = version.SelectedItem.Value;
string serverPath;

if (FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName != "")
{
    if (selectedValue == "1")
    {
        // check extension of file before uploading
        if (FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName == "MyApp.apk")
        {
            serverPath = "C:/MyPath/MyApp.apk";
            FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(serverPath);
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('file has been uploaded successfully');window.location.href = '" + Request.RawUrl + "'; ", true);
        }
        else if (FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName == "MyApp.ipa")
        {
            serverPath = "C:/MyPath/MyApp.ipa";
            FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(serverPath);
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('file has been uploaded successfully');window.location.href = '" + Request.RawUrl + "'; ", true);
        }
        else
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('Please select MyApp file to upload');window.location.href = '" + Request.RawUrl + "'; ", true);
        }
    }
}
```

But what I'm getting is, the system will upload the file first and display an alert message that I had set.

How can I display an error message first (wrong file chosen), before the default upload bar shows up?

Comment: comapre strings. `if (FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName.Equals(selectedFileName)) { // proceed with upload }`

Answer (score 0):

if you need to check before page is being submitted, you can use client-side onchange event for input type=file, something like this:

```
    <html>
        <body>
            <form>
                <div>
                    file: <input type="file" id="fileupload" />
                </div>
            </form>
            <script>
                document.getElementById('fileupload').addEventListener('change', onUpload);
                function onUpload(e){
                    var files = this.files;
                    if ( files && files.length==1 
                        &&  ( files[0].name.toLowerCase() === "myapp.apk" || files[0].name.toLowerCase() === "myapp.ipa"  )
                        )
                    {
                        //allow to submit file
                    }
                    else{
                        //cancel form submission
                        this.value = "";
                        alert('Please select MyApp file to upload');
                    }
                }
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: but I wonder how can I force the user to choose again or remove the selected file?